# Default values for options object in javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there a (much) better way of writing this? I am using Dojo. Maybe mixing in would work?

```
  ajaxValidate: function(value, options){

    // Set some defaults
    options.ajaxInvalidMessage = options.ajaxInvalidMessage || "Value not allowed";
    options.ajaxStore = options.ajaxStore || null;
    options.ajaxFilterField = options.ajaxFilterField  || 'name';
```

There doesn't seem to be a `||=` operator and this looks very verbose to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a mixin is a cleaner approach. That way, you can also explicitly group your defaults into a single object.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/mixin.html

```
ajaxValidate: function (value, options) {
    options = dojo.mixin({
        ajaxInvalidMessage: "Value not allowed",
        ajaxStore: null,
        ajaxFilterField: "name"
    }, options);

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method you show:

```
obj.prop = obj.prop || "default";
```

...is a pretty common idiom, but personally I find an if statement more descriptive even though it actually adds a couple of characters:

```
if (!obj.prop) obj.prop = "default";
```

If you want a more general way to do it you can write a function something like the following (I'm not familiar with Dojo - perhaps it already has such a function):

```
function addDefaults(obj, defaults) {
    for (prop in defaults)
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            obj[prop] = defaults[prop];
}
```

Which you'd then use in your code snippet as:

```
ajaxValidate: function(value, options){

    addDefaults(options, {
       ajaxInvalidMessage : "Value not allowed",
       ajaxStore : null,
       ajaxFilterField  : 'name'
    });
```

Note that in my `addDefaults()` I'm using the [`hasOwnProperty()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) which tests whether the property exists in your object. This is subtly different to the `||` syntax you started with which tests whether the property is "truthy".